# Check sheet name and run the code related to the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I' am looking for a code to check Sheet names initially like A, B, C. If sheet A exist then it should run the code which is goto A1: else it should go to B and check if Sheet B exist, if sheet B exist then it should run code below B1, Same way for sheet C as well.

Ex:

```
For I = 1 to worksheets.count 
    If Sheets(i).Name = "A" Then 
       GoTo A1 
    Else 
       GoTo B 
    End If 
Next I
```

Comment: Don't use `GoTo`, that creates spaghetti code. Instead, perhaps create a separate subroutine for A, B, and C, and then call each based on your existing loop and check of the sheet's `.Name`.

Comment: please suggest alternative

Comment: Can you please help me with the code

Comment: When i tried the above code it is not checking the sheet name at all, it is directly going to first-line and then Else and executing statement under Else

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be solved by using **ElseIf** or **Select Case**.
Please try with the following 2 cases.

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    Select Case Sheets(i).Name
        Case "A"
            ' Coding for "GoTo A1"
        Case "B"
            ' Coding for "GoTo B1"
        Case "C"
            ' Coding for "GoTo C1"
        ...
    End Select
Next i
```

Or

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Sheets(i).Name = "A" Then
        ' Coding for "GoTo A1"
    ElseIf Sheets(i).Name = "B" Then
        ' Coding for "GoTo B1"
    ElseIf Sheets(i).Name = "C" Then
        ' Coding for "GoTo C1"
    Else
    ...
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific macro you want to run on each sheet and you want to trigger all of them to run at once, you can organize it like so:

```vb
Sub Main()
    Call SheetA_Macro
    Call SheetB_Macro
    Call SheetC_Macro
End Sub
```

If you have a lot of sheets you can automate the calling of these macros by naming them all the same thing and placing them into the sheet's code module, which would let you call them in this way:

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sht.Name).MySheetSpecificMacro
    Next Sht
End Sub
```

If you have an unknown sheet and you want to call only that specific sheets macro, then you will want to do it like above but without the loop.

```vb
Call ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MyUnknownSheetObject.Name).MySheetSpecificMacro
```

Remember that the macros must be placed into the sheet's code module and should all be named the same thing.

Comment: By the way, can someone elaborate on why the compiler complains "Method or data member not found" if I do `Sht.Macro` but not when I do `Sheets(Sht.Name).Macro`?

Comment: What if Sheet B doesnt exist, how will my code skip that and call Sheet C

Comment: If you have an unknown number of sheets then I suggest using the `For Each Sht in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` because that will ensure the code only looks at what you DO have.

Answer (score 0):

### Worksheet Related Code

- Writes the list of worksheet names to an array.
- Loops through the array attempting to find an existing worksheet using the `WorksheetExists` function.
- Continues with the worksheet that exists (if any).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ApplyToFirstFound()
    
    Const wsNamesList As String = "A,B,C"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim wsNames() As String: wsNames = Split(wsNamesList, ",")
    
    Dim wsName As String
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(wsNames)
        If WorksheetExists(wb, wsNames(n)) Then
            wsName = wsNames(n)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next n
    
    ' You could continue with...

    If n > UBound(wsNames) Then
        MsgBox "No worksheet exists.", vbCritical, "ApplyToFirstFound"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    MsgBox "The first found worksheet is named '" & wsName & "'.", _
        vbInformation, "ApplyToFirstFound"
    ' ... continue...
    
    ' ... or with a different code for each worksheet (I've used the same.).
    
    Select Case wsName
    Case "A"
        MsgBox "Applying to '" & wsName & "'.", _
            vbInformation, "ApplyToFirstFound"
    Case "B"
        MsgBox "Applying to '" & wsName & "'.", _
            vbInformation, "ApplyToFirstFound"
    Case "C"
        MsgBox "Applying to '" & wsName & "'.", _
            vbInformation, "ApplyToFirstFound"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "No worksheet exists.", vbCritical, "ApplyToFirstFound"
    End Select
    
End Sub

Function WorksheetExists( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal WorksheetName As String) _
As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    WorksheetExists = Not ws Is Nothing
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Resume Next
End Function
```